# How to make the NSButton above a NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

i'm having two NSButtons. Both button were with images. This is what i created [buttons] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYXIE.png) the problem is the star button always located behind the leaf button. how can i bring it front. (searching for Mac osx not iOS.)
UPDATE:
this is what i got during first mousehover  [image], got this during second mouse over [image]

Comment: In your nib file just delete the star button from the view hierarchy and add it again

Comment: star button located above the leaf button... i deleted and added the star button. after only i facing this problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
[starButton removeFromSuperview];
[self addSubview:starButton positioned:NSWindowAbove relativeTo:nil];
```

Also, NSView supports the method

```
 sortSubviewsUsingFunction:context:
```

implement that to simply sort the views.. requires more code but seems more clean.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bringSubviewToFront to force a view appear "on top" of another view:

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

If you want to change the order of the views in the storyboard designer, just drag the view you want on top below the other view in the left menu. The topmost view is always the one displayed last in the list.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: sorry its supported only in iOS... i'm for MAC

Comment: i tried... first time of mouse hover, the star button appears above the leaf button, after the second mouse hover, sends to back....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of star I am using `A`, and `Apple` instead of Leave.

You are doing this way:
[image]

You need to change the buttons location as :

[image]

**Bring button `A`  after `Apple`**.

then you will see as per your requirement .

[image]

Comment: already i'm having like this... i subclassed these two buttons. at the first mouse hover its appears properly and at second mouse hover it( say Button A) went behind the Apple button.

Comment: if these are buttons, then their ordering cant be change by just mouse hover. Can you tell what kind of buttons are you using.

Comment: * star button: style-square, type-momentary change and * leaf button: style-Bevel, type - momentary push in

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:leafButton];
[parentView bringSubviewToFront:starButton];
```

Comment: sorry its supported only in iOS... i'm searching for Mac

Answer (score 0):

To bring a subview to the front on macOS, do this:

```
NSView *superView = myObject.superview;
[myObject removeFromSuperview];
[superView addSubview:myObject]; // brings to the front
```