# NSProgressIndicator doesn't work more than once

Tags: macos, progress-bar, nsprogressindicator

I'm using NSProgressIndicator in my ETL app for OS X and hat I'm indicating with it is the current state od downloading sources of given pages.

Everything is fine when in a first run - works like  charm. The problem appears when I hit the reset button and try to run whole process one more time - the indicator is fully loaded at the begining.

Sound to me like I need to restore it to the default values but I have no clue how...

```
- (IBAction)showAction:(id)sender
{
    [[self panel] display];
    NSLog( @"Show action" );
}

- (IBAction)restartETLAction:(id)sender
{
    [etl restart];
    [self setProgressBar:nil];
    NSLog( @"Restart action" );
}

- (void) showProgressBarPanelWithTitle:(NSString *) title
{
    [[self panel] setTitle:title];
    [[self panel] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
}

- (void) updateProgressBarPanelWithProgressLevel:(double) progressLevel
{
    [[self progressBar] setDoubleValue:progressLevel];
    [[self progressBar] startAnimation:self];
}

- (void) hideProgressBarPanel
{
    [self.progressBar stopAnimation:self];
    [[self panel]  orderOut:self];
}
```

Of course I have some properties:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSPanel *panel;
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. I needed to `nil` some objects just to restart te whole process of the application. So after that the app creates new instances of this objects and the are clean so the `NSProgressIndicator` works like it should.

Answer (score 0):

bring the NSProgress indicator front as shown below and try again. comment your error if anything u got

[image]

Comment: Do you mean something like this?

http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/3789/zrzutekranu20130530o085.png

This screen shows how it looks right now.

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398854/how-to-make-the-nsbutton-above-a-nsbutton) for concept... your are showing a progress indicator in seperated view... add the progres indicator below the controls...

Comment: I understand what you mean, I guess... But look at the screen I posted. There is only the indicator inside the panel view and I cannot changes its position.

Comment: `[progressBar stopAnimation:self];` and `[progressBar startAnimation:self]` the two statements enough to control a progress control. i think you are adding extra load to the program. if i'm not wrong, u r showing panel with a progress indicator and a title. if you want to hide the progress indicator just use `-setHidden:`.